# How to update Excel Table using VBA while maintaining table's formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that defines several Excel tables which include both source data and functions using the source data.  For example, a table named MyTbl consists of three "source columns" and one formula column ...

```
Part   Price  Qty  Extended Price
------ -----  ---  --------------
Shoe   5.50   10   =(MyTbl[[#ThisRow],[Price]])*(MyTbl[[#ThisRow],[Qty]])
...
```

Periodically, the source columns must be replaced by values from a CSV file, but the formula column(s) should remained unaffected.  The file is something like:

```
Shoe,5.65,98
Coat,12.65,223
...
```

How do I "refresh" the source columns while maintaining the existence of the Excel Table and its formulas?  I'd like to do this in VBA as the CSV file does not have a consistent name or path.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to try something, i.e., start writing some code, so we have something to help you with. I think the best approach is to delete all but the first row of the table, use the Listobjects `Resize` method to get the right number of rows and copy in the new columns. I have a [somewhat related post](http://yoursumbuddy.com/copy-table-data-while-not-breaking-references/) on my blog.

Comment: And here's a [good tutorial](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/Excel2007TablesVBA.asp) by Jan Karel Pieterse. One more thing - you'll especially want to look at the ListColumn object.

Comment: @DougGlancy Thanks for your direction and help.  I was able to incorporate code from your blog and the tutorial to get the result I needed.  Here is the code:

Comment: @DougGlancy I would upvote your comments as useful, but I don't have the necessary reputation to do so.

Comment: I'm glad they were helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Doug Glancy for his suggestions.

The original question dealt with the loading of a .csv into a listobject.  I ended up loading the data from the csv into a listobject on a new sheet.  I was then able to merge a source listobject into a  target listobject while maintaining the additional columns (and formulas) the target maintained using the procedure below.  This procedure clears the data that is not needed, removes rows if the source contains less rows than the target, copies the data, and resizes the listobject.

Assumptions within this solution

- source list object contains some number of columns less than the target
- both list objects contain a single header row (I did not test anything more than a single header row)

```vb
Private Sub CopyTableData(loSource As Excel.ListObject, loTarget As Excel.ListObject)  
    Dim lSourceRowCount As Long
    
    With loTarget
        If .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count <> loSource.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count Then
            ' clear of target area should clear target num rows and source num columns
            .Range(.Cells(1,1).Address, .Cells(.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, lSource.RefersToRange.Columns.Count)).Clear
            
            ' clear rows if source has less than target
            If .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count > loSource.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count Then
                For i = .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count To loSource.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count + 1 Step -1
                    .DataBodyRange.Rows(i).Clear
                Next i
            End If
            
            ' resize list object
            lSourceRowCount = loSource.HeaderRowRange.Rows.Count + _ 
                              loSource.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
            
            .Resize .Range.Cells(1).Resize(lSourceRowCount, .Range.Columns.Count)
        End If
        loSource.DataBodyRange.Copy .DataBodyRange.Cells(1)
    End With
End Sub
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the post and reply. I had to make some changes to [your code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16284608/2227743) to make it work for me.

```
Private Sub CopyTableData(loSource As Excel.ListObject, loTarget As Excel.ListObject)
' This routine updates the first columns of 'loTarget' Excel table
' with the content of 'loSource' Excel table,
' resizing 'loTarget' table rows to suit.
' Does not update headers or remaining columns of 'loTarget' table.
' Requires 'loTarget' to have at least as many columns as 'loSource'.

Dim lSourceRowCount As Long, i As Long

With loTarget
    If .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count <> loSource.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count Then
        .Parent.Range(.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1), .DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Offset(.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count - 1, loSource.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count - 1)).Clear
        
        ' clear rows if source has less than target
        If .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count > loSource.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count Then
            For i = .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count To loSource.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count + 1 Step -1
                .DataBodyRange.Rows(i).Clear
            Next i
        End If

        ' resize list object
        lSourceRowCount = loSource.HeaderRowRange.Rows.Count + _
                          loSource.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count

        .Resize .Range.Cells(1).Resize(lSourceRowCount, .Range.Columns.Count)
    End If
    loSource.DataBodyRange.Copy .DataBodyRange.Cells(1)
End With

End Sub
```